# How to tell default value from clearing with FromBody in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have coded in C# for years, but I am new to ASP.NET Core.  I have created a Web API where I generated my Model classes from an existing database and used the scaffolding to create a Controller for each model that gives me Get, Put, Post, and Delete.  My question is how do I know if the caller is clearing a value vs the value is the default for the C# object?

For example, in Vue.js I send

```
var sendstuff = {userName: "TestUser1", userId: 7, email: null};
```

In C#, my user object has

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
```

In my controller, my put method begins

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutUsers([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] User user)
```

My User instance in the database is TestUser1, 7, test@test.com, purple.  The User that comes into PutUsers is TestUser1, 7, null, null.

At this point, I want to compare the values sent in for user 7 to the values in the database for user 7.  However, since both FavoriteColor (that is not sent) and Email (that is sent) look the same as they both appear as null, how do I know whether or not it should be changed?  I want test@test.com to be cleared, but I want purple to remain.

It seems my only other option is to have Vue.js send in every single column for every table, with the values either the original value I don't want changed or the new value.  This doesn't feel right.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to accept a Generic Json-Object and checking wether or not the Properties are set.

Most Json Frameworks will be able to cast to a specific Object from the Json Object so you won't even need to change your further code.